# catch complex focus in winform app

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I have complex app and I lose focos in some cases. I use one form and dockpanels. I load dynamic elements on form so on start I don't have all elements on form.

The problem is that i can't figure out where the focus is. I have event gotfocus and lostfocus on form.activecontrol but It can't catch moment of lose. Maybe problem is with dockpanels or dynamic elements which are added in some cases. Do you know How to trace every focus chanage in whole app? Is It possible?

Thx

Comment: If you want to globally capture individual control focus events unfortunately I don't think that's possible at all. Main window does not recieve the `WM_KILLFOCUS` and similar messages which controls do recieve.

Comment: So the only solution is register event on every possible control (GotFocus and LostFocus)?

Comment: Yes, which probably brings you to reconsider the whole idea of tracing the focus. Debug your focus problems by narrowing it down to few controls and then closely inspect those.